# Im a Python-preferred student, and have a question about linked list

Tags: python-3.x, linked-list

I understand for other languages such as c++, where they have a pointer to locate a variable's position directly, use linked list for the memory efficiency. However, in Python there is no pointer. So isn't linked list not worth to use since there is no way to directly access to each node? I saw alot of coding challenges or coding interviews related to linked list. Why do people still use linked list in python whereas we have an awesome built-in array?

Comment: Python does not have built-in arrays. Python has built-in lists.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things to note here.

Firstly, a `pointer` in a `LinkedList` is different than a `pointer` in `C` or `C++`. Though they act the same by "pointing" to something else, they are not the same thing.

Next, a `LinkedList` pointer points to the next item in the `LinkedList`, while a `C pointer` points to a location in memory. That is a key difference.

Another thing to note is that Python, is for the most part, written in `C`, so things that are important to `C` are also important to Python.

Some benefits of a LinkedList are that it saves a lot of memory, since it only accounts for filled values vs an array which allocates memory for the entire size of the array. The other big benefit is that a LinkedList can exist anywhere in memory (thanks to the pointers!), whereas an array must stay in a static location. This is a benefit from a speed, memory optimization, and security standpoint.

It should also be noted that Python doesn't really have a built in `array` so to speak, they have a built in `list`, so that is something to catch yourself with.

Answer (score 0):

It is to deepen your understanding of the data structure underneath Python's built-in implementation. You should know how they work, even though they're abstracted away in Python. Richard Feynman said, "Know how to solve every problem that has been solved." In programming you will encounter many, many things that have been done already better than you could ever do them, and you should use those tools that people have opened sourced and created for you to use, but you should also know how they work.